# How to sum columns in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I know it may be basic, but i'm noob to SQL.
So, i have this query:

```
select nome_equipa, 
sum(case when (resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as empates,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado > resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante > resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as vitorias,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado < resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante < resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as derrotas
from jogo, equipa
group by nome_equipa
order by vitorias desc;
```

Outputting this:

[image]

so, the sum columns are not in my db and are calculated by SQL.
These columns are the number of victories, losses and draws of a team. now i want to display the number of points of each team. I thought that would be easy, like adding just `(empates*1 + derrotas*0 + vitorias*3) as pontos` to the select, but it does not work. i think it's because the columns i am trying to sum are calculated and not in the db.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
WITH list AS (
select nome_equipa, 
sum(case when (resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as empates,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado > resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante > resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as vitorias,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado < resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante < resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as derrotas
from jogo, equipa
group by nome_equipa
order by vitorias desc
)
SELECT nome_equipa
     , empates
     , derrotas
     , vitorias
     , (empates*1 + derrotas*0 + vitorias*3) as pontos
  FROM list ;
```

which is equivalent to sticky bit's second option.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that would be easy, like adding just `(empates*1 + derrotas*0 + vitorias*3) as pontos`

It is in fact that easy. You just cannot reference the column aliases here, you have to repeat the expressions:

```
...
-- begin expression for `empates`
sum(CASE
      WHEN resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante
           AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
            OR resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado
               AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN
        1
      ELSE
        0
    END)
-- end expression for `empates`
* 1
+ 
<analog for the other two>
...
pontos
...
```

Or you `SELECT` again from your query, then you can access the columns by it's alias of the then lower level query.

```
SELECT *,
       empates * 1
       + derrotas * 0
       + vitorias * 3 pontos
       FROM (<your current query>) x;
```

Comment: thank you very much! can you just explain me what's the x for?

Comment: That's a (table) alias. Every derived table (a "table" that isn't a physical table (or view or mview) but build by a subquery) needs one so that it can be referenced. For "normal" tables (views, mviews) you can use it too but it isn't mandatory unless you join the same table twice and need to resolve ambiguities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478460/how-to-use-multiple-selects-in-same-query-without-messing-everything can you please help me here?