# How to use multiple selects in same query without messing everything

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

So, i have this query

```
  SELECT nome_equipa,
  count(id_golo) AS golos_marcados FROM equipa,golo 
  WHERE golo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa 
  GROUP BY golo.equipa_id_equipa, nome_equipa ORDER BY count(id_golo)DESC
```

which outputs this table

[image]

then i have this other query

```
SELECT nome_equipa,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS empates,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado > resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante > resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS vitorias,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado < resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante < resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS derrotas
FROM jogo,
     equipa
GROUP BY nome_equipa
ORDER BY vitorias DESC
```

which outputs this:

[image]

All i want to do is place the two columns side by side without bugs.

tried this

```
select nome_equipa, count(id_golo) as golos_marcados,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as empates,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado > resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante > resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as vitorias,
sum(case when (resultado_visitado < resultado_visitante) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa or (resultado_visitante < resultado_visitado) and jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa  then 1 else 0 end ) as derrotas
from jogo, equipa, golo
where golo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
group by nome_equipa
order by vitorias desc
```

but it returned this:

[image]

Here is the ER diagram:

[image]

Comment: Sample data and an explanation of the logic would really help.

Comment: Please add the schema of each table, and also try to avoid using Portuguese names for tables, is a good practice to use allways english as standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Is hard to follow up the logic with the above information, so I can't give you the exact query you have to run. But What I can suggest how to arrive to it.

I would recommend to use WITH statement. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

Sth like:

```sql
WITH goals AS (
        SELECT 
        nome_equipa,
        count(id_golo) as golos_marcados 
        FROM equipa, golo 
        WHERE golo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa 
        GROUP BY nome_equipa
     )

SELECT nome_equipa,
       g.golos_marcados,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado = resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante = resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS empates,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado > resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante > resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS vitorias,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (resultado_visitado < resultado_visitante)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa = id_equipa
                    OR (resultado_visitante < resultado_visitado)
                    AND jogo.equipa_id_equipa1 = id_equipa THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS derrotas
FROM jogo      -- equipa TABLE IS NO NEEDED
LEFT JOIN goals g
ON goals.nome_equipa = jogo.nome_equipa
GROUP BY nome_equipa
```

Then you join with the other query and by nome_equipa and add the column. And that's it.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand what to do next, can you see if what i did helped understanding? made some edits on the post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with` as was mentioned above. Also `join` will give you same results:

```
select bla, lorum, ipsum from table1
join (select bla, bla1 from table 2) as select_row on select_row.bla = table1.bla
```

Comment: sorry, did not understand it. can you please say where to use the with as above?

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to jump into your project, English would be preferred as stated by Pato Navarro !

First of all, the structure of your queries could be improved, for instance see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) about the `FROM` clause and the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html) about the `window` functions. Let's try for the first query (not tested !) :

```
SELECT e.id_equipa
     , e.nome_equipa
     , count(*) AS golos_marcados
  FROM equipa AS e
 INNER JOIN golo AS g
    ON g.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa 
 GROUP BY g.equipa_id_equipa
 ORDER BY golos_marcados DESC
```

Let's try for the second query (not tested !) :

```
SELECT e.id_equipa
     , e.nome_equipa
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN j.resultado_visitado = j.resultado_visitante) AS empates
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN (j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitado > j.resultado_visitante) OR (j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitante > j.resultado_visitado)) AS vitorias
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN (j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitado < j.resultado_visitante) OR (j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitante < j.resultado_visitado)) AS derrotas
  FROM equipa AS e
  LEFT JOIN jogo AS j
    ON j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa     -- equipa plays at home
    OR j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa    -- equipa plays outside
 GROUP BY e.id_equipa
 ORDER BY vitorias DESC
```

If both queries run well, then you can merge them together like this (not tested !) :

```
WITH goal AS (
SELECT e.id_equipa
     , e.nome_equipa
     , count(*) AS golos_marcados
  FROM equipa AS e
 INNER JOIN golo AS g
    ON g.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa 
 GROUP BY g.equipa_id_equipa
 ), result AS (
SELECT e.id_equipa
     , e.nome_equipa
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN j.resultado_visitado = j.resultado_visitante) AS empates
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN (j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitado > j.resultado_visitante) OR (j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitante > j.resultado_visitado)) AS vitorias
     , count(*) FILTER (WHEN (j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitado < j.resultado_visitante) OR (j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa AND j.resultado_visitante < j.resultado_visitado)) AS derrotas
  FROM equipa AS e
  LEFT JOIN jogo AS j
    ON j.equipa_id_equipa = e.id_equipa     -- equipa plays at home
    OR j.equipa_id_equipa1 = e.id_equipa    -- equipa plays outside
 GROUP BY e.id_equipa
)
SELECT g.id_equipa
     , g.nome_equipa
     , g.golos_marcados
     , r.empates
     , r.vitorias
     , r.derrotas
  FROM goal AS g
 INNER JOIN result AS r
    ON g.id_equipa = r.id_equipa
 ORDER BY g.golos_marcados DESC, r.vitorias DESC
```

At the end of the story, the main issue is not about your queries, but it is about the structure of your tables : the resultado_visitado and resultado_visitante of the jogo table should be calculated from the table gojo, otherwise your data may be inconsistent !